# Stormpath OAuth 2.0 unsupported grant type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, stormpath

Per Stormpath [documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/authentication.html#oauth2-password-grant), for the password grant_type, all one would need to do is make a post request like below:

```
POST /oauth/token
Host: myapi.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password
&username=user@example.com
&password=theirPassword
```

However, this does not work and returns "unsupported_grant_type". In my configuration, password grant is enabled. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the request body had to be on one line

```
grant_type=password&username=user@example.com&password=theirPassword
```

Comment: This is correct -- the body must be a single line as per the OAuth2.0 standard.

Comment: @rdegges Thanks for updating your documentation!

Comment: This is the right answer! Updated the .NET docs: https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/authentication.html#oauth2-password-grant